# Flutter : read data from firebase using Getx

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am trying to display the data on the page
But this error appears to me
Is there a solution to this?

controller

```
RxInt pprofit = 0.obs ; 

void onInit() async{
      super.onInit();
    // TODO: implement onInit

      CollectionReference fprofits = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('admin');
      await fprofits.doc('profits').get().then((value) {
        pprofit = value.data()['profits'];
      }); }
```

iam trying to get this value only
[image]

error

```
    Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
        pprofit = value.data()['profits'];
```

Comment: I hope someone can help me

Comment: Have you double checked that value.data() is actually the value you're expecting? Try printing it out or setting a breakpoint there to check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can hel you

```
CollectionReference fprofits = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

final collection = await fprofits.collection('admin').doc('profits').get();
final data = collection.data();
print(data);
```

you can transform it in Map

```
CollectionReference fprofits = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

final collection = await fprofits.collection('admin').doc('profits').get();
Map<String, dynamic> data = collection.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
print(data);
```

tell if worked for you